# Apex 5.1:How Create Multiple Region Display Selector on Master-Detail-Detail IG

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have following tree logic 
Master
     Detail
    Detail 1    Detail 2

I added a region display selector for Master-Detail, now I want to add another Display Selector
for Detail 1 & Detail 2 as shown in the pic.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouzaM.png)

Answer (score 2):

Multiple regions of type ***Region Display Selector*** are not possible on same page.

You can achieve similar functionality by changing your selector regions type to ***Static Content*** and Template to ***Tabs Container***. Later, modify all child region's parent to respective selector region. Once this is done, sub regions will appear as tabs. Also, note that you won't get Show All option like Region Display Selector.

[Link](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=114083:10) to example on apex.oracle.com